# How to access the top level object property from low level object in java script

Tags: javascript, object

I'm having object like below code. And i want to access the top level(parent) variables from low level objects(child object - inner object ).
For example in folder structure if we want to go to the parent folder we put like ../ . Likewise how to access the parent object properties from child object.

```
var a = {
    b: {
        c: 5,
        h: {
            d: {                 
                e: function(){
                alert(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

In this above example code i want to access the property 'c' from 'd'.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: The same code was i'm tried

Comment: As far as I know there is no such short cut methods in JS. Objects are  just key value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no upwards facing relationship in JavaScript so there isn't a trivial way to do this.

Take, for example, this:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
var c = {};

a.c = c;
b.c = c;
```

Now you have `c` and want to get its parent. What would you get? There are two parents.

What about this?

```
c.c = c;
```

Now `c` is its own parent.

The closest you can come is to do a search of the tree to find matches for the object and write your own logic (which will probably be custom for your specific case) to determine which values to get back. It would probably need to keep a list of objects it had searched already so you don't end up with infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can try this (fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8twvpo58/)

In that case you are referring to the absolute position of course, but I'm not aware of another option

```
var a = {
        b: {
            c: 5,
            h: {
                d: {                 
                    e: function(){
                    alert(a.b.c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };



a.b.h.d.e();
```